Direction of steepest ascent for functions $\mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable, and $n > 1$. Is there any generalization of the idea of `direction of steepest ascent' to such functions? The obvious limitation is that the function is $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued, i.e., we don't know what 'descent' looks like as this space doesn't have an order.
One idea I had was to simply continue saying that the gradient is the direction of steepest ascent. This involves finding the gradient of $f$: now, I thought the gradient at a point is the Jacobian matrix $Df(x) = (d_{x_i}f_j)_{i,j}$, an $(n \times m)-$matrix that doesn't live in $T_x(\mathbb{R}^m)$ (which consists of $m-$dimensional vectors). But this is confusing: isn't the gradient supposed to live in the tangent space in some way? So, this makes me think that the gradient of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined differently (so it lives in the tangent space), which gives me some hope for a solution.
Another idea I had was by recalling that the direction of steepest ascent, $v$, satisfies the relation $\nabla f(x) \cdot v = \min \{\nabla f(x) \cdot w: w \in T_x(M)  \} $. Thus, we need the Riemannian structure of Euclidean space to make sense of this. Maybe we can say that $v$ should be the minimizer of some function $F:T_p(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $F$ involves the gradient $Df(x)$. But I'm not sure what $F$ could be here.
I'm still learning diff. geo. so I may be missing some key facts here.

Is there a reason you want to apply this concept?

It depends on what you are trying to do. There is Pareto optimisation, for example.

@aschepler No, I'm just interested in the generalization of the idea, and if it doesn't work, then what might fail. This is particularly because, in the Riemannian setting, we do have an inner product, so it is a natural question to ask?
